# RSA Encode with Crypto++ and Decode with c# RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, c++, crypto++, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Good morning,

I have a client-server application communicating over UDP sockets.
I want to encode the communications with RSA ( encode the keys) and AES to encode the datagram.

The client side is in c++ and the server side in C#

I am curently trying to  encode the AES IV an Key  with RSA but i get an error when decoding in c#:

**Exception type :** System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException

**Exception message :** Cryptography_OAEPDecoding

Here is my encoding code ( client side, c++ )
**[EDIT] CHanged RSAES_PKCS1v15_Encryptor to  RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor**

```
const CryptoPP::Integer n("107289343054719278577597018805838066296333011963085747309982087864392842699433873606133118875978275304651444098131280023618603357722259282514858925191134541966986361546234507079678544203468616135436686852577772762581654429498496768721214543879181421353486700409082948114039206485653595743465270256058198245113.");
const CryptoPP::Integer e("17.");   

[...]

void Crypto::CryptRSA(const std::string & bufferIn, std::string & bufferOut, const CryptoPP::Integer &n, const CryptoPP::Integer &e)
{
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
    CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey pubKey;
    pubKey.Initialize(n, e);

    CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor encryptor(pubKey);

    size_t ecl = encryptor.CiphertextLength(bufferIn.size());
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock ciphertext(ecl);

    encryptor.Encrypt(rnd, (CryptoPP::byte*)bufferIn.c_str(), bufferIn.size(), ciphertext);

    bufferOut = std::string((char*)ciphertext.data(), ecl);

}
```

And here is my decoding code ( server side. C# )

```
private static string _keyN = "107289343054719278577597018805838066296333011963085747309982087864392842699433873606133118875978275304651444098131280023618603357722259282514858925191134541966986361546234507079678544203468616135436686852577772762581654429498496768721214543879181421353486700409082948114039206485653595743465270256058198245113";
private static string _keyE = "17";
private static string _keyD = "50489102613985542860045655908629678257097887982628586969403335465596631858557116991121467706342717790424208987355896481702872168339886721183463023619357421741798172532326737925480536247565713413538718832057918801452980775480097195493999319542331774866185094818177243836015292183598722700529776296282728256145";

[...]

public static byte[] DecryptRSA(byte[] encrypted)
{
    BigInteger n, e, d;
    BigInteger.TryParse(_keyN, out n);
    BigInteger.TryParse(_keyE, out e);
    BigInteger.TryParse(_keyD, out d);

    CspParameters csp = new CspParameters();
    csp.KeyContainerName = "RSA Test (OK to Delete)";
    csp.ProviderType = 1; 
    csp.KeyNumber = 1;    

    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;

    var param = new RSAParameters()
    {
        Modulus = n.ToByteArray().Skip(1).ToArray(),
        Exponent = e.ToByteArray().Skip(1).ToArray(),
        D = d.ToByteArray().Skip(1).ToArray(),
    };            

    rsa.ImportParameters(param);

    return rsa.Decrypt(encrypted.ToArray(), true);
}
```

So, I am wondering what I did wrong in my code.

In c++ i can encode and decode my datagrams but when i try to decode with c# it does'nt work.

Thank you and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I *thought* Microsoft does not support OAEP for RSA. You might also try to use PKCS padding, thought it is considered [less secure](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/06/21/bad-couple-of-years-for-cryptographic/). You might also be interested in [Cryptographic Interoperability: Keys](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/25487/cryptographic-interoperability-keys).

Comment: @jww I already read this article with no success. It might be due to it not being up to date (11 years old) or me not understanding it correctly. Also, in this article they put the keys in a file whish I cant do right now due to some limitations.

Comment: Based on `Cryptography_OAEPDecoding` it looks like .Net is using OAEP padding. Your Crypto++ encryptor is using PKSC padding. Maybe you should use [`RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor`](https://cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_r_s_a_e_s___o_a_e_p___s_h_a___encryptor.html). Also be careful of the default hash.

Comment: @jww Thank you for trying to help me. Unfortunately  I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

[BigInteger.ToByteArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns the value as a **little-endian**.

While `RSAParameters` fields are indeed big-endian (As explained [here](http://blog.wezeku.com/2011/03/12/net-rsaparameters-endianness/)).

You may try something like :

```
 Modulus = n.ToByteArray().Reverse().ToArray()
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I did as you said, but I still have the same error